# Kali Linux Hotspot

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, kali-linux, wireless-hotspot

I'm having a hard time trying to make a hotspot in Kali Linux. I want to make a hotspot so that I can connect wirelessly to my phone, but I can't seem to keep my current WiFi connected to Linux when the hotspot is on.

I searched around the internet and I can't find anything on it, I know in windows you can have a hotspot and share the current WiFi that you're connected to. Please help, thanks.

Comment: Don't try to make a hotspot in Kali Linux. Kali Linux is a distribution geared at [professional penetration testers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me), i.e. you put in on an USB stick, walk into a company, and start hacking their computers. It's not meant for stuff like hotspots. Use any other distribution, and you'll make your life a lot easier.

Comment: *It's not meant for stuff like hotspots* or any usage as a daily driver desktop Linux. And anyone asking this kind of questions is certainly not Kali's target audience.

Comment: Lol, I know what Kali Linux is for, I was just seeing if u can use the same adapter

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to this is,  it's normal behavior

Your "current wifi" will be disconnected when you enage the drivers for another use. Like using "airmon-ng start wlan0" uses the command "rf-kill" to disable all network activity from the desktop.

This is the intended behavior. Just get an atheros based USB adapter if you want to connect to a access point & host a fake AP.

For instance I have 3 atheros 9k adapters in my Kali box, then you can monitor multiple channels at a time. I would recommend you read this 
https://www.kali.org/download-kali-linux-revealed-book/

Best regards,